# Why is my moved domain still serving a placeholder from the previous hosting company?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, cloudflare

This may be basic stuff, but I'm a programmer, so fairly technical on the server/systems side, but not proficient.

I've moved two domainnames from one hosting to another, and can't get one to work. The domainname is cvnp.be and as you can see, it has the Easyhost placeholder. Easyhost is my previous hosting company.

However, I've set up Cloudflare for this domain, and as you can see in a [DNS lookup](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#whois|type=domain&&value=cvnp.be), the two Cloudflare nameservers are being used.

In Cloudflare, I've added the necessary records, just like I did for the domain that is working:

[image: Cloudflare]

The IP address you can see, is the one from my new hosting company (Interserver):

[image: Interserver]

It's been more than 12 hours (but not 24), I've purged the Cloudflare cache, and still I see the Easyhost placeholder... Where is this placeholder being served from, and how can I get it to show the contents I've uploaded to Interserver (an Orchard CMS site)?

Comment: What are you expecting? I see a "Welcome to Orchard" setup page which wants me to enter in some database information and choose a recipe.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me - What do you want the orchard password to be ?

Comment: Haha! Be nice, @Iain!

Comment: lol, then it must be some caching locally to me... Clearing my browsercache seems to do the trick, although I did it in the past too. Maybe then the nameservers hadn't updated yet, I dunno... Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

When you're not sure that your browser is caching or your local dns or your Internet provider dns's are caching dns records, you can try to open your domain over proxy like proxy.org or propagationproxy.com. Of course, that makes sense only if you're positive that you have correctly set NS's and dns zone on new NS's. If you do dns lookup and it's good, but you keep opening old hosting, this should help. 
Another thing you should do is to set different index pages on old and new hosting, that way it's easier to see which server served your request.